# Signin page redirect to 404 when first load vue js 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

When the application starts, I am setting the default path to **users**, if authentication fails, then it will navigate to **sign in**. But it redirects to 404.

```
const routes = [
{
  path: "/signin",
  name: "signIn",
  component: () => import("@/path"),
},
{
 .........
},
{
  .......
},
{
  path: "/",
  redirect: "/users",
  component: adminLayout,
  //needed for nav gaurd
  //meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  children: [
    {
      path: "dashboard",
      name: "dashboard",
      component: dashboard,
      meta: { 
        title: 'Dashbaord' 
      }
    },
    {
      path: "users",
      component: () => import("path"),
      meta: { 
        title: 'Users' 
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: "",
          component: () => import("path"),
          meta: { 
            title: ''
          }
        },
        {
          path: ":id/profile",
          component: () => import("path"),
          meta: { 
            title: 'Profile' 
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    
  ],
},
{
  path: "*",
  redirect: "/404",
},
{
  // the 404 route, when none of the above matches
  path: "/404",
  name: "404",
  component: () => import("@path"),
},
```

];

If i set **redirect: "/dashboard"** or **redirect: "/signin",**, then it works fine.
Also if I navigate to the right path, like "http://localhost:8080/signin" it will work. But if I only type "http://localhost:8080" hit enter it will go to 404 page

**Note** : first my **users** component like this and its works fine

```
{
        path: "users",
        component: () => import("path"),
        meta: { 
          title: 'Users' 
        },
},
{
        path: ":id/profile",
        component: () => import("path"),
        meta: { 
          title: 'Profile' 
        },
    },
```

Please help me to understand the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you are redirecting the user to the correct path?

Comment: Just noticed that your route name has an uppercase letter. ```signin``` and ```signIn``` are not the same route names.

Comment: Yes, I am redirecting to users.

if (!this.isAuthenticated) {
      console.log("Not Authenticated");
      this.$router.push({ name: "signIn" });
    }

Comment: if "isAuthenticated" true, it works fine

Comment: Also if I navigate to the right path, like "http://localhost:8080/signin" it will work. But if I only type "http://localhost:8080" hit enter it will go to 404 page

Comment: Add / before each path. ```path: "/users"``` It is a reason why you are getting 404.

Comment: path: "/users" Not working

Comment: If you notice, I put path " " for the first child.

Comment: Hmm, other things in the router look fine. I am pretty sure that you are redirecting the user to a path that does not exist. Check all your redirects and make sure that names/paths are correct.

Comment: I am redirecting in my ADMIN module, and the code is if (!this.isAuthenticated) {
      console.log("Not Authenticated");
      this.$router.push({ name: "signIn" });
    }

Comment: when I first go to "http://localhost:8080" it redirects to "http://localhost:8080/users" then it redirects to "http://localhost:8080/signin" then it redirects to "http://localhost:8080/404"

Comment: Redirection flow is it folows as  "users => signin => 404"

Comment: As mention in the question, it works fine until Route flow changes

Comment: Do you have any redirects on /signin page?

Comment: I tested it locally and everything works as expected.

Comment: I will check the whole modules, which related to users

Comment: I had a redirect in the one modal component when authentication is failed. That's why it's going to 404. Thank you so much for your guidance and for taking the time to solve my isuue.